# Enable websocket tomcat on ELB

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Can't seem to find out a solution for this, but when I running my application on tomcat behind a load balancer, I get this below error:

**ERROR** 
cpr.AsynchronousProcessor  - Invalid request state. Websocket protocol not supported.

**Note :-**

Enabled the proxy protocol using below command.

**#aws elb create-load-balancer-policy --load-balancer-name Mag-ELB --policy-name EnableProxyProtocol  --policy-type-name ProxyProtocolPolicyType --policy-attributes AttributeName=ProxyProtocol,AttributeValue=True**

created policy to the back-end instance port.

**#aws elb set-load-balancer-policies-for-backend-server --load-balancer-name Mag-ELB --instance-port 80 --policy-names EnableProxyProtocol**

Answer (score 0):

I didnt set this policy and managed to run the websocket with tomcat 7 behind AWS ELB by setting Load Balancer Port = 80 and Instance Port = 80 (Procotol TCP).

I didnt get to make this work with SSL though.